# Using simplemembership within ninject repository - via API & standard controller

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I am building a fairly small sized mvc4 application. I want to use the simple membership provided as in time I can it being useful for the social stuff.

I want to be able to take advantage of the webapi within the project as I am building an ios application and would like for it to be able to use the same registration/account details. I have added an API area to the site.

I am using ninject for my injection so I have created a repository and have taken the default membership registration component and put it into this.

My Account controller and the apicontroller use the same repository.

```
 public RegisterModel RegisterLocalUser(RegisterModel model)
    {
        try
        {



            WebSecurity.CreateUserAndAccount(model.UserName, model.Password,
                                             new
                                             {
                                                 Mobile = model.Mobile,
                                                 FirstName = model.FirstName,
                                                 LastName = model.LastName,
                                                 Email = model.Email,
                                             });
```

Creating a user using the site works fine however when I try to use the api via fiddler to create a user I run into an issue of

> {"Message":"An error has occurred.","ExceptionMessage":"You must call the \"WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection\" method before you call any other method of the \"WebSecurity\" class. This call should be placed in an _AppStart.cshtml file in the root of your site.","ExceptionType":"System.InvalidOperationException","StackTrace":"   at WebMatrix.WebData.SimpleMembershipProvider.VerifyInitialized()\r\n   at WebMatrix.WebData.WebSecurity.VerifyProvider()\r\n   at WebMatrix.WebData.WebSecurity.CreateUserAndAccount(String userName, String password, Object propertyValues, Boolean requireConfirmationToken)\r\n   at MySite.Web.Repository.AccountRepository.RegisterLocalUser(RegisterModel model) in c:\@Projects\Site\Site\Site.Consumer.Web\Repository\AccountRepository.cs:line 28\r\n   at MySite.Web.Areas.API.Controllers.AccountController.RegisterLocal(RegisterModel data) in c:\@Projects\Site\Site\Site.Consumer.Web\Areas\API\Controllers\AccountController.cs:line 26\r\n   at lambda_method(Closure , Object , Object[] )\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.<>c_*DisplayClass13.b*_c(Object instance, Object[] methodParameters)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.Execute(Object instance, Object[] arguments)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.<>c_*DisplayClass5.b*_4()\r\n   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskHelpers.RunSynchronously[TResult](Func`1 func, CancellationToken cancellationToken)"}

Adding a breakpoint within the repository the CreateUserAndAccount is never completed.

I have a custom DependancyResolver needed to allow the api and mvc stuff to work

```
public class NinjectDependencyScope : IDependencyScope
{
private IResolutionRoot resolver;

internal NinjectDependencyScope(IResolutionRoot resolver)
{
    Contract.Assert(resolver != null);

    this.resolver = resolver;
}

public void Dispose()
{
    IDisposable disposable = resolver as IDisposable;
    if (disposable != null)
        disposable.Dispose();

    resolver = null;
}

public object GetService(Type serviceType)
{
    if (resolver == null)
        throw new ObjectDisposedException("this", "This scope has already been disposed");

    return resolver.TryGet(serviceType);
}

public IEnumerable<object> GetServices(Type serviceType)
{
    if (resolver == null)
        throw new ObjectDisposedException("this", "This scope has already been disposed");

    return resolver.GetAll(serviceType);
}
}

public class NinjectDependencyResolver : NinjectDependencyScope, IDependencyResolver
{
private IKernel kernel;

public NinjectDependencyResolver(IKernel kernel)
    : base(kernel)
{
    this.kernel = kernel;
}

public IDependencyScope BeginScope()
{
    return new NinjectDependencyScope(kernel.BeginBlock());
}
}
```

Has someone else been able to find a work around to get these components working together?

Thank you

Comment: Is your default `AccountController` decorated with `InitializeSimpleMembershipAttribute`?

Comment: Thanks Jasen!!!! Lovely when its such a simple fix. Add this as an answer and I will accept it if you like. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error dump suggests you are not using the `InitializeSimpleMembershipAttribute` for your `AccountController`.

Either decorate your new account controller with `InitializeSimpleMembershipAttribute` or move that `Websecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection()` to your Global.asax startup code.

Of course, this ignores the dependency issue and I don't have a good answer for that as I don't bother injecting WebSecurity.

1. WebSecurity is a static class
2. You'd only need to call InitializeDatabaseConnection once at startup. With the attribute usage it's called each time the controller is accessed.
3. Which means you must inject an initialized WebSecurity into your repository.